# including a c/c++ header file in fortran subroutines

Tags: c, header, include, fortran

I have a library written in C/C++ which is declared, by its developers, to have a Fortran interface. The interface would be enabled including a header file *.h and calling a classical subroutine. I would like to compile my Fortran program linking also that library.
The library has been tested already and it works.

Here it is the main program:

```
! Main program
INCLUDE 'pastix_fortran.h'

Program TEST
IMPLICIT NONE
call GO_PASTIX
END PROGRAM TEST
```

The routine GO_PASTIX is

```
SUBROUTINE GO_PASTIX
IMPLICIT NONE

pastix_data_ptr_t :: pastix_data
integer :: pastix_comm
pastix_int_t :: n, rhs, ia(NCOLS+1), ja(NNZER)
pastix_float_t :: avals(NNZER), b(NROWS)
pastix_int_t :: perm(NROWS), invp(NROWS), iparm(64)
real*8 :: dparm(64)

call pastix_fortran(pastix_data,pastix_comm,n,ia,ja,avals,perm,invp,b,rhs,iparm,dparm)
END SUBROUTINE
```

Whereas in the file pastix_fortran.h the types of variables used in the subroutine are defined:

```
#define PASTIX_INT_KIND    4
#define pastix_int_t       INTEGER(kind=4)
#define pastix_uint_t      unsigned INTEGER(kind=4)
#define pastix_data_ptr_t  INTEGER(kind=4)
#define MPI_PASTIX_INT     MPI_INTEGER4
#define pastix_float_t     REAL(kind=8)
#define MPI_PASTIX_FLOAT   MPI_REAL8
```

Using VS2010 I added the option to preprocess file with /fpp and I did not forgot to add all include directories and files. However the compiler says that:

for the header lines: "Warning 1 warning #5117: Bad # preprocessor line"

for the fortran subroutine: "error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [PASTIX_DATA_PTR_T]" and so on for the rest of the variables...

How can I work out this?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the `#define` for the type is not correctly processed. I think, one of the possible problems is the way you include the header file in Fortran, as you are doing it via a *Fortran statement* instead of a *preprocessor directive*. So, probably it is only included, after the file had been already preprocessed. Therefore, the `#define` options in the .h file are not resolved by the preprocessor.

Changing the `include()` statement into an `#include` preprocessor directive may solve the problem.

Comment: Yes. And also not forget the `-cpp` or `-fpp` flag for the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
#define pastix_uint_t      unsigned INTEGER(kind=4)
```

is going to cause most Fortran compilers a wee problem since the language has never supported unsigned integers using this or any other syntax.  Some deviant implementations may have supported them, but they are definitely not standard.

Comment: `MPI_INTEGER4`, `MPI_REAL8` etc are [in the MPI standard](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node32.htm), as optional types.  They're obviously horrible, but one does see them sometimes.